# Excel IF Formula Not Working Correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel IF formula that is not working correctly and I cannot figure out why.

Here is the formula:

```
=IF(D17<=200%, C17*130%, IF(D17<=150%, C17*120%, C17*140%))
```

- When D17 > 200% it is properly multiplying C17 times 140%.
- When D17 <= 200% it is properly multiplying C17 times 130%
- But, when D17 is <=150%, it is NOT multiplying C17 by 120%. Instead it multiplies by 130%

Why is that?

Comment: You are checking for it to be under 200, then under 150. It will never make it to the 150 check.

Answer (score 3):

```
=IF( D17<=200%,
 'THEN
    C17*130%,
 'ELSE
     IF(D17<=150%,
       'THEN
           C17*120%,
       'ELSE
          C17*140%)
    )
```

You need to rethink the logic.
As written you will ALWAYS have `C17*130%` executed when `D17<=200%` is true.

`=C17*IF(D17<=150%,120%,IF(D17<=200%,130%,140%))` should work - untested.
The double IF will return the multiplier factor

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(D17<=200%,C17*130%,IF(D17<=150%,C17*120%,C17*140%))
```

Your first if checks D17 <= 200%, and its false checks if D17 <= 150%

If it's not below 200, why would it be below 150?

You need to start with the most restrictive if -

```
IF(D17<=150%,C17*120%,IF(D17<=200%,C17*130%,C17*140%))
```